# Money not received in Exchange from Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cpu-mining, gpu-mining

So i sent out some coin to an exchange from my monero gui wallet. Sent it at 8:23 this morning and it is now 10 pm and i still havent gotten it on my exchange. It was set to x1 priority and as far as i can tell its been sent on my wallet and the blockchain. Any one know whats up ?

Answer (score 1):

Exchanges will provide you with a payment ID, so they know how to credit the deposit.  Perhaps you didn't use one.  Whether or not you used one, you can prove you sent the transaction with the transaction private key, so either way you should reach out to the exchange support and request that they credit your account.

Comment: You think i should contact the exchange or maybe the wallet ? yes i do have all the info to prove i sent the money

Comment: First, contact the exchange to tell them the time and amount of the payment.  With that alone, they may credit your account.  Or they may then ask for the transaction private key.

Comment: Okay, will do, I appreciate the help